# How to check for auotocorrelation in models with lots of separate time series

Tags: regression, time-series, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, autocorrelation

Suppose we fit a statistical model to time series data with lots of "sites". If we produce a (p)acf plot to check for autocorrelation, do we need to do one for each of our seperate time series in the model i.e. for each site? I'm not sure how this could be done with e.g. thousands of sites. I have noticed that one can compute the average acf for models with several time series e.g.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/itsadug/vignettes/acf.html
However, I have also seen that this is not always performed e.g.
http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/ecostats_chap.html
So Im not sure which method is most appopriate.